# How can I avoid main plot stopping when closing a second figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, button, callback

I have a small python script that displays a Matplotlib plot. This main plot is continously updated in a loop.
In this plots figure, I have a button that when pressed, executes a callback that opens a second plot in a figure. The main plot continues to update like expected while this second "Pop up" figure is open.

The issue arises when I close this second figure.
I would have expected the main loop to continue to update the main figure window, but it stops execution.

Even more strangely, when I close the main figure window, the update loop continues again.

Does anyone have any suggestion of how I can get the main loop to continue to update the main figure window after the second figure window is closed?

```
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

def main():
    # Create a figure and axis that we will display the main window on
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
 
    ax_pop = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.14, 0.2, 0.04])

    pop_up_window_button = Button(ax=ax_pop, label='Open second window', hovercolor='0.975')

    # A callback function for the button press event
    def pop_up_window(event):
        """
        Pop up a second window
        """
        # Plot some random values to a matplotlib graph
        print("Plotting some more random values in second window")
        x = [random.randint(1, 100) for n in range(100)]
        y = [random.randint(1, 100) for n in range(100)]
        fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
        ax1.scatter(x, y) 
        ax1.axis('off')

        plt.pause(0.1)  # Need to pause to allow the image to be displayed


    # Add a callback to the button press event
    pop_up_window_button.on_clicked(pop_up_window)

    live_view = True
    while live_view:
        # Plot some random values to a matplotlib graph
        print("Plotting some random values")
        x = [random.randint(1, 100) for n in range(100)]
        y = [random.randint(1, 100) for n in range(100)]
        ax.clear() 
        ax.scatter(x, y) 
        ax.axis('off')
        ax.set_title('Live view') 

        plt.pause(0.01) # Need to pause to allow the image to be displayed
        time.sleep(1)



    print('Done')

    return True

# Main entry point of script
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if main():
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        sys.exit(1)
```

The main figure that is plotted:
[image]

The second figure that is plotted:
[image]

When this second figure is closed, the main plot stops updating.

```
Plotting some random values
Plotting some random values
Plotting some random values
Plotting some random values
Plotting some random values
Plotting some random values
Plotting some more random values in second window  < We clicked on the button here>
Plotting some random values
Plotting some random values
Plotting some random values
< second figure is closed. Console output is paused, main plot stops updating
....
....
If we close the main figure, the console output starts up again>
Plotting some random values  
Plotting some random values
Plotting some random values
Plotting some random values
Plotting some random values
```

Comment: I can't fully reproduce the problem. When I run your script, the second figure is blocking until closed -- as it should be. It is hence a bit of a mystery to me why your while loop is evaluated when opening the second figure. However, setting interactive mode to on with `plt.ion()` at the start of the script results in the desired behavior. I am using matplotlib 3.7.1 with a Qt backend. If using `plt.ion()` does not solve the problem for you, you may want to try switching to another backend.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That is strange that you cannot fully reproduce the problem. I am using TkAgg, in case that it the problem. After your message, I switched to QtAgg, but the issue remains. When you close the second figure, does the main loop that updates the first figure restart?

Comment: With `plt.ion()`, the main loop never stops. Without `plt.ion()`, the main loop is blocked until the figure is closed but then resumes. Again, this is exactly what I would expect given your code, hence I think there is something particular about your setup that results in this issue. Are you using an IDE (such as pycharm) or using a notebook? Those can interact with interactive events as well.

Comment: Actually, iif your backend is TkAgg, you can't be using a notebook. Might still be the IDE, if you are using one.

Comment: Ah, you may be onto something: based off what you said, I switched from a pyenv environment to a Conda one, and it appears to work like you would expect! TkAgg is being used by Matplotlib in both environments. I have replicated the same issue using both VsCode and command line in Ubuntu. However, I am running Matplotlib 3.7.1 in the affected environment, and 3.1.2 in the working environment. I will see what happens when I downgrade.

Comment: Sure enough, when I downgrade matplotlib it works as expected! :-) The commands were: pip uninstall matplotlib followed by pip install matplotlib==3.1.2 . If you want to post that as the answer I can accept it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries. Happy this helped you but since the issue seems to have been a subtly broken matplotlib installation, I don't think this is likely to be of value to anyone else.